# How many times can a paladin use Lay on Hands per day?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The rules for [Lay on Hands](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin) state that:

> Each day she can use this ability a number of times equal to 1/2 her paladin level plus her Charisma modifier.

If the paladin's charisma score is 18, this gives her a modifier of +4.  If her level is 4, do the rules mean she can use Lay on Hands 4 times per day:

> 4 + 4 = *8*
>
> *8* / 2 = **4**

or 6 times per day:

> 4 / 2 = *2*
>
> *2* + 4 = **6**

Comment: oh, I see it now.  "1/2 (her paladin level plus her charisma modifier)" vs "(1/2 her paladin level) plus (her charisma modifier)"

Comment: In general it's usually safe to assume that any operations like this are grouped just how language modifiers are grouped - As in, modifiers such as "1/2 [of]" are grouped exclusively with the nearest following subject, which is "her paladin level" in this case. Only figure otherwise if it is explicitly stated to be otherwise. As Envision said, referring to the "sum of her paladin level plus her Charisma modifier" would be the English equivalent of wrapping the addition in parentheses.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Apply the (1/2) multiplier to the paladin level only. Your example paladin can use Lay on Hands 6 times per day.

This is consistent with mathematical order of operations; in `0.5 * <paladin level> + <CHA>`, you only apply the multiplication to the paladin level. In order to indicate an equation such as  `0.5 * (<paladin level> + <CHA>)`, It should be worded "a number of times equal to 1/2 *the sum of* her paladin level plus her Charisma modifier", to emphasize the grouping.

This also fits with other class abilities, such as the cleric's channel energy ability: "A cleric may channel energy a number of times per day equal to 3 + her Charisma modifier." There are many such abilities that add an ability score modifier to another number (often based on class level). In the case of Lay on Hands, the "other number" is 1/2 paladin level.

Answer (score 12):

You would not divide the modifier by 2 so it would be 6. Anytime an ability says it is usable X amount of times + Y stat Mod you do not divide the Modifier.

The calculation would be like this.

(X/2)+Y = uses

X = Class Level
Y = Stat Modifier

Also if you are interested in extra uses there are feats such as [this one](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-lay-on-hands---final) for almost every class ability with limited uses.

Answer (score 7):

Six. The ½ only applies to the paladin class level, not to the Charisma modifier.